# uploading a video

Tags: file-upload, video

I have tried to upload a video to my magento back-end 1.9 with no luck, I  modified my php ini file but I am still unable to upload my file, which is   5MB  [image: capture]
 I would like to be able upload a video that can be played on the product page and cms pages, please I would like a free solution and I am not using youtube and vimeo. I have tried a lot of the methods on this topic but no one has had any luck also.

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution would be to upload the video via FTP or SSH - this will allow you to get around the file upload limit.

Just because you update the upload_max_filesize in your version of the php.ini file doesn't mean that there isn't another configuration file higher up on the server that's overriding it.

I hope this helps...

Comment: okay using the method how do I link back to the file, so I can reference the video on the pages or products.

Comment: So, let's say you have a domain like www.AwesomeProducts.com.  If you FTP into the site, and upload a file named video1.mov into the /video/ folder, you'd then be able to link to it at: http://www.AwesomeProducts.com/video/video1.mov